# SQL Server.. trying to change schema name

Tags: sql-server

If I have a DB named myDB with one of the user defined Schema as Schema1..Is the following query correct if I want to create a simple table?

```
use myDB
CREATE TABLE Schema1.Users
(UserID bigint NOT NULL,
UnID nvarchar(100),
UserName nvarchar(100),
PRIMARY KEY (UserID))
```

It prefixes dbo in the table name

Comment: just figured out the problem myself..Schema name wasn't correct in my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schema name wasn't correct in my query..sorted out the problem myself